# Batch operations are not working after parse migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, batch-processing

I am using parse Rest API from client side i.e iOS application.

Batch operations are not working after migration to Azure. I have changed path from `/1/classes/ClassName to /parse/classes/className`.

I am getting error as:

> {
>     "code": 107,
>     "error": "cannot route POST \classes\className"
>   }

Is there anything to do? 
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Any help to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please check your publicServerURL & serverURL . I don't believe you have mounted it correctly.

Comment: also what is your mount path set too?

Comment: mouth path is set to "parse"

Comment: change that path. See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try ..
```

http://api-url/parse/classes/classname

```
Also update - parse lib at client side.(latest version is parse-1.6.14.min.js)
```

Comment: I am using Rest API not library .

Comment: Please  provide more detail about how u configure server . So i can help on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Code 107 normally is a issue with the mount path & `publicServerURL`. Try change it too be

```
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/';
```

And your publicServerURL as

```
publicServerURL: 'http://api-url/parse/',
```